# Incorrect $HOME env variable for a newly created user

Tags: linux, ubuntu, environment-variables, home

On my Ubuntu machine, I logged in as "olduser" and created "newuser" using the following command:

```
adduser --system --home /usr/share/newuser --no-create-home --ingroup newgroup --disabled-password --shell /bin/false newuser
```

This adds a new line:

```
newuser:x:104:1001::/usr/share/newuser:/bin/false
```

to my `/etc/passwd` file. But when I log into the machine as 'newuser' (Either by sshing into the machine as `newuser` or by running `sudo -u newuser bash` from a shell), my home directory is set as `/home/olduser`.

```
echo $HOME
```

gives

```
/home/olduser
```

The same command mentioned above works as expected on a Debian machine but not on the Ubuntu machine.

Why could this be happening?

I tried changing the home directory using the command

```
usermod -m -d /usr/share/newuser newuser
```

This also didn't help.

Comment: run `mkhomedir_helper newuser` and see what you get

Comment: Apart from the answer concerning sudo not changing the home directory, how do you SSH in, when the user's shell is `/bin/false` ?

Answer (score 3):

`sudo` doesn't necessarily update the `HOME` variable for the new user.  If you want `HOME` updated, use the `-H` or `-i` options.  For example:

```
sudo -Hu newuser bash
```

Alternatively, you can add this line to the `/etc/sudoers` file to have `sudo` automatically update `HOME` and other relevant variables:

```
Defaults        env_reset
```

Many distributions already have `env_reset` as the default.

#### Documentation

From the section of `man sudo` that describes environment variables:

> HOME
> Set to the home directory of the target user if -i or -H are
>   specified, env_reset or always_set_home are set in sudoers, or when
>   the -s option is specified and set_home is set in sudoers.

See also `man sudoers`.